# Is there an R function that implements the finite element method?

Tags: r, finite-element-analysis

Is there an R function that can solve a partial differential equation using the [finite element method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method) (Strang and Fix, 1973)?

Based on the wikipedia list of [finite element software packages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_element_software_packages), the method has been implemented in Fortran, C. Both Fortran and C can be called by an R function, but I do not see any such functions in CRAN.

---

Strang and Fix. An Analysis of The Finite Element Method. Prentice Hall, 1973.

Comment: I'd be astounded if anyone had ever implemented an FE code in R

Comment: it really wouldn't make sense to implement finite element methods in *native* R, but you could hope for an interface to one of the existing (open- or closed-source) implementations in a lower-level language (analogous to the `deSolve` package for ODEs) ...

Comment: There was an overview of the packages dealing with ODEs and PDEs 
in the R Journal, a couple of years ago:
http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2010-2/RJournal_2010-2_Soetaert~et~al.pdf

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd thanks for the link; I have added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a book which tackles this topic exclusively:

> Finite Element Computations in Mechanics with R: A Problem-Centered
>   Programming Approach 1st Edition Khameel Bayo Mustapha
>
> CRC Press  Published April 20, 2018

More information can be found here: https://www.crcpress.com/Finite-Element-Computations-in-Mechanics-with-R-A-Problem-Centered-Programming/Mustapha/p/book/9781138501621

Answer (score 3):

There is a new package that uses Finite Element Method (FEM).
I think that's one of the first steps for using FEM in R.

[fdaPDE](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fdaPDE/)

Answer (score 1):

I have found no evidence for such a function:

The following quote from an article in the R Journal article on ODE's and PDE's implies that such functionality was not present at the time of publication (2010):

> Extending the PDE approach to ﬁnite elements (Strang and Fix, 1973) would open up the application domain of R to any irregular geometry.

---

[Karline Soetaert, Thomas Petzoldt and R. Woodrow Setzer, 2010. Solving Differential Equations in R. The R Journal Vol. 2/2, December 2010](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2010-2/RJournal_2010-2_Soetaert~et~al.pdf)